# How to calculate rank with group by in sql?

Tags: sql, group-by, rank

Suppose if I have `table1` as following

```
Category  Brand  Value     
A           A1     4
B           B1     7
C           C1     8
A           A2     3
B           B2     4
C           C2     6
A           A3     9
B           B3     10
C           C3     1
A           A4     5
```

Now if I want to calculate rank for each brand but grouped by category how do I go about it?

Something like

```
Select rank() (over value)
from table
group by category
```

Expected output is this:

```
Category      Brand Value     Rank
A               A3    9         1
A               A4    5         2
A               A1    4         3
A               A2    3         4
B               B3    10        1
B               B1    7         2
B               B2    4         3
C               C1    8         1
C               C2    6         2
C               C3    1         3
```

Comment: What is your database? Show expected result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like this.
See this official documentation on [DENSE_RANK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) for more details

```
select brand, category, dense_rank() over(partition by category order by value desc) as dr
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add a `PARTITION BY` clause to your `RANK()` call, specifying the category as the partition.

```sql
SELECT RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY value) rnk
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY category, rnk;
```